# How can I style only those Buttons which are in a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf

In App.xaml I have styled all my Buttons.

```
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
    </Style>
```

I realized if the Button is in a DataGrid then I not need a margin. I have a lot of DataGrid and I put this code into all of them one by one.

```
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
```

Is there a more clever way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `Style` for `DataGrid` and within that, add child control style to particular modification.

If you want to add this `Style` to all the DataGrids, no need to define`Key`.

```
<Style x:Key="dataGrid" TargetType="DataGrid">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add resource file at Windows or User control level so that it will apply all child controls as below,

```
<Window.Resources>
     <Style  TargetType="DataGrid">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
<Window.Resources>
```

or

```
<UserControl.Resources>
     <Style  TargetType="DataGrid">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a style with the key in the Window.Resources or App.Resources as shown below.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="dataGridButtonStyle">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Wheat"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then apply the style to the control using the StaticResource with the key(in this example key name is dataGridButtonStyle)

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey= dataGridButtonStyle}" Content="Hello"/>
```